# Missing bits/c++config.h in WSL Ubuntu 22.04 VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to use VSCode with WSL on windows 11 but it seams that some libraries are missing.
As soon as I `#include <iostream>` an error appear :
`unable to open source file "bits/c++config.h" (dependency of "iostream") C/C++(1696)`

In fact it's true that I don't have any `bits/c++config.h` file in `/usr/include/c++/11/`.
But the program compile well with no problem.

How can I add missing headers in this folder So that VSCode stops showing me this error

Comment: It's in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits`.

Comment: Well I've tried to add `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits` to`includePath` in my `c_cpp_properties.json` but the error is still here.

Comment: Do you have this file in that location?

Comment: Yes I  have it..

Comment: You can find my project code [here](https://github.com/FelixDubois/init-cpp), it is very small, maybe I did something wrong with CMake or with the VSCode config

Comment: I'm not familiar with VSC's stock intellisense, so I'm not sure what's wrong here. I prefer Clangd.

Comment: Yeah ! You were right, after installing `Clangd` extension, the error is gone ! Thank you ! It's a bit slow but does the job